# Open 404 page with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# skip rules below this for files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]


# rewrite to the physical php page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# otherwise, redirect to serve.php
RewriteRule ^/?$ serve.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ serve.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
Options -Indexes
```

If whether an ID or a file cant be found, it should open a 404 page. How to implemented that in this htaccess file ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please give some context to your question to help us understand the issue and provide a solution? Is this your current .htaccess file? Have you tried to implement a solution to your problem?

Comment: yes, this is my current htaccess file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask